# Spotify-Connect Fails to Change Volume on USB Sound Card

Tags: usb, audio

Good Evening, Gentlemen!

I successfully installed spotify-connect on my Raspberry Pi 1 B.
I can start it as follows and it works well:

`sudo /home/pi/spotify-connect-web.sh --username XXX --password XXX --bitrate 320 --name RaspberryPi --device 1`

(`--device 1` selects the USB sound card as output device.)
My problem is that when I change the Volume of Spotify, spotify-connect changes the volume of the Raspberrys *internal* sound card instead of the USB sound card!

I've tried blacklisting the internal sound card, but then I get the following error: `audio_arg_parser.add_argument('--mixer', '-m', help='alsa mixer name for volume control', default=alsa.mixers()[0])`
I think it means that I have to specify the mixer via a `--mixer` argument, but everything I've tried failed.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Solution:

I've solved my problem by simply using another (newer) implementation of librespot, the library behind spotify-connect-web. Here's a small how-to:

- Make the USB sound card the default:

`sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`

Change

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

to

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

- Reboot.
- Test whether sound works. `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000`
- Go to [git/TheBigFatTony/librespot/releases](https://github.com/TheBigFatTony/librespot/releases), get the link to the newest zip file.
- Download the thing. `wget https://github.com/TheBigFatTony/librespot/releases/download/XXXX.XX.XX/librespot.zip`
- Unzip. `unzip librespot.zip -d .`
- Now you can run and test it, and play around with the parameters. How it works for me: `./librespot --name RaspberryPi`

Everything works now, including volume control. Additionally, this version of the library appears to be less buggy and more responsive.

## Start automatically upon reboot:

Create a systemd-service (`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/librespot.service`) with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Librespot is an open source client library for Spotify.

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
TimeoutStartSec=15
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
ExecStart=/home/pi/librespot --name RaspberryPi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start the service and test whether it works:

`sudo service librespot start`

This command may be useful for debugging:

`systemctl status librespot.service`

Start the service automatically on bootup:

`sudo systemctl enable librespot.service`

## Librespot updater script:

Put the following code into /home/pi/updater/updater.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "last time the updater was started: $(date +"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")" > last_time_updater_was_started.txt
# get the link to the latest TheBigFatTony/librespot release
latest="$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/TheBigFatTony/librespot/releases/latest | grep browser_download_url | cut -d '"' -f 4)"
echo "latest: ${latest}"
# if unsuccessful curl OR empty var OR bad beginning OR bad ending...
if [[ ! $? -eq 0 ]] || [[ -z "$latest" ]] || [[ ! $latest == https://github.com/TheBigFatTony/librespot/releases/download/* ]] || [[ ! $latest == *.zip ]]; then
    echo "URL NOT FOUND OR BAD"
else
    echo "URL FOUND"
    # if there is an update...
    if [ "$latest" == "$(<current_version.txt)" ]; then
        echo "No new version found."
    else
        echo "New version found! Downloading..."
        # download update but install only if download successful.
        wget_output=$(wget -q --output-document=latest.zip "${latest}")
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Commencing update..."
            sudo service librespot stop
            unzip -o latest.zip -d /home/pi/
            chmod +x /home/pi/librespot
            sudo service librespot start
            echo -n "${latest}" > current_version.txt
            echo "last time an update was installed: $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" > last_time_an_upate_was_installed.txt
            echo "UPDATE COMPLETE"
        else
            echo "Download unsuccessful"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Create a systemd-service (`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/libspotify-updater.service`) with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Updater for librespot.

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/updater
ExecStart=/home/pi/updater/updater.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create a systemd-timer (`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/libspotify-updater.timer`) with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=An example timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 04:00:00
# Optional
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Enable the service and the timer: `systemctl enable libspotify-updater.timer`, `systemctl start libspotify-updater.timer`, `systemctl enable libspotify-updater.service`, `systemctl start libspotify-updater.service`